# vee-validate - Independent forms validation with separated methods

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I currently have two forms in two separated steps, each one with its own submit button.

If I use
$validator.validateAll()
all the inputs on the page will be validated but I do need the validation only for that form.

That's what I have:

```
<v-form ref="form1">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="Account"
        v-validate="'required|numeric'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Account')"
        label="Account"
        data-vv-name="Account"
        name="account"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="PhoneNumber"
        v-validate="'required|numeric'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Phone Number')"
        label="Phone Number"
        data-vv-name="Phone Number"
        name="phone"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-btn color="primary"
        @click="NextStep()"
        >
        Next
    </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

And the second form

```
<v-form ref="form2">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="Email"
        v-validate="'required|email'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Email')"
        label="Email"
        data-vv-name="Email"
        name="email"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="Address"
        v-validate="'required'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Address')"
        label="Address"
        data-vv-name="Address"
        name="Address"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-btn color="primary"
        @click="FinalStep()"
        >
        Next
    </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

With this JS on my *.vue file:

```
async NextStep(){
    if (await this.$refs.form1.validate()) {
        this.SubmitOrder['Account'] = this.Account
        this.SubmitOrder['PhoneNumber'] = this.PhoneNumber
        this.ConfigureNumber = true;
    }
},
async FinalStep(){
    if (await this.$refs.form2.validate()) {
        this.SubmitOrder['Email'] = this.Email
        this.SubmitOrder['Address'] = this.Address
        this.ConfigureNumber = true;
    }
},
```

If I remove the `$refs` and change it to `$validator.validateAll()` it works but doesn't go to the next step because is validating the next inputs.

`data-vv-scope` (https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/scopes.html) won't work for me because I do need different methods (It will have more on each one)

Any idea what's wrong here?

Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using data-vv-scope="something" referenced inside validateAll('something'):

```
<v-form data-vv-scope="form1">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="Account"
        v-validate="'required|numeric'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Account')"
        label="Account"
        data-vv-name="Account"
        name="account"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="PhoneNumber"
        v-validate="'required|numeric'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('Phone Number')"
        label="Phone Number"
        data-vv-name="Phone Number"
        name="phone"
        color="primary"
        required
        ></v-text-field>
    <v-btn color="primary"
        @click="NextStep()"
        >
        Next
    </v-btn>
</v-form>

async NextStep() {
    await this.$validator.validateAll('form1').then((isValid) => {
        if (isValid) {
          this.SubmitOrder['Account'] = this.Account
        this.SubmitOrder['PhoneNumber'] = this.PhoneNumber
        this.ConfigureNumber = true
        } else {
          this.ConfigureNumber = false
        }
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as below

```
const results = Promise.all([
  this.$validator.validate('field1'),
  this.$validator.validate('field2')
]);

const areValid = (await results).every(isValid => isValid);
```